# BST based implementation of set

Tags: c++, set, binary-search-tree

## Purpose of program

I'm attempting to implement **set ADT**. So far, I have the interface and some of the functions such as **insert()**, **contains()**. Though it seems like my insert function does not work because whenever I output the contents of set it shows an empty set.

To implement insert, I've used helper function that would recursively look for value in the set, and if it's not there it would insert it and return true.

Here's the interface of set class in set.h:

```
#include <iostream>

class set {

    // Private type
    struct treenode {
       int value;
       treenode* left;
       treenode* right;

       treenode(int val)
          : value(val),
            left(nullptr),
            right(nullptr)
       { }
    };

    size_t set_size;
    treenode* root;

    // Recursive function that creates and returns an exact
    // copy of the tree structure rooted at original
    static treenode* copynodes(treenode* original);

    // Recursive function that deallocates all of the
    // nodes in the tree structure rooted at node
    static void deallocatenodes(treenode* node);

    // Recursive function called by print to output the
    // values using in-order traversal
    static void printhelper(std::ostream &out, treenode* node){
        if (node != nullptr) {
            if (node->left != nullptr) {
                printhelper(out, node->left);
                out << ", ";
            }
            out << node->value;
            if (node->right != nullptr) {
                out << ", ";
                printhelper(out, node->right);
            }
        }
    }

    static bool containshelper(int i, treenode *node);

    static bool inserthelper(int i, treenode *node);

public:

    // Default constructor
    set() : set_size(0), root(nullptr) { }

    // Copy constructor
    set(const set &s) : set_size(s.set_size), root(nullptr) 
    {
        root = copynodes(s.root);
    }

    // Initializer list constructor
    set(std::initializer_list<int> init) : set_size(0), root(nullptr) 
    {
        for (auto el : init) {
            insert(el);
        }
    }

    // Copy assignment
    set& operator=(const set &s) {
        if (&s != this) {
            deallocatenodes(root);
            root = copynodes(s.root);
            set_size = s.set_size;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    // Returns true if the value i is in the ordered set
    bool contains(int i) const;

    // If the value i is not in the set,
    // insert it and return true;
    bool insert(int i);

    // Remove everything from the set
    void clear();

    // Returns the number of items in the set
    size_t size() const;

    // Returns whether or not the set is currently empty
    bool empty() const;

    // Print out the contents of the set, in order from smallest to largest
    void print(std::ostream &out) const {
        out << "{";
        printhelper(out, root);
        out << "}";
    }

    // Destructor
    ~set() {
        deallocatenodes(root);
    }
};

inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const set &s) {
    s.print(out);
    return out;
}
```

## Implementation of functions

Here's what I implemented in set.cpp:

```
#include "set.h"
#include <iostream>

set::treenode* set::copynodes(treenode *original) {
    
    if(original == nullptr) {
        return nullptr;
    }
    
    treenode *copiedTree = new treenode(original->value);
    
    copiedTree->left = copynodes(original->left);
    copiedTree->right = copynodes(original->right);
    
    return copiedTree;
}

void set::deallocatenodes(set::treenode *node) {
    
    if(node != nullptr) {
        deallocatenodes(node->left);
        deallocatenodes(node->right);
        delete node;
    }
    
}

bool set::containshelper(int i, set::treenode *node) {
    
    if (node == nullptr)
       return false;

    // i found
    else if (node->value == i)
       return true;

    // Recursively search for i
    else if (i < node->value)
       return (containshelper(i, node->left));
    
    else
       return (containshelper(i, node->right));
    
}

bool set::inserthelper(int i, set::treenode *node) {
    
    if(node == nullptr) {
        node = new treenode(i);
        return true;
    } else if(i == node->value) {
        return false;
    } else {
        if(i < node->value){
            return (inserthelper(i, node->left));
        } else if(i > node->value){
            return (inserthelper(i, node->right));
        }
        
        return false;
        
    }
    
}

bool set::contains(int i) const {
    
    return containshelper(i, root);
    
}

bool set::insert(int i) {
        
    if(inserthelper(i, root) == true) {
        set_size++;
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    
}

void set::clear() {
    set_size = 0;
    deallocatenodes(root);
}

size_t set::size() const {
    return set_size;
}

bool set::empty() const {
    return (set_size == 0);
}
```

## Testing the implementation

Testing file main.cpp looks as follows:

```
#include "set.h"
#include <iostream>

void output(const set& s) {
    std::cout << "SET OUTPUT: " << std::endl;
    std::cout << s.size() << " " << s.empty() << " " << s << std::endl;
    std::cout << "END OF OUTPUT." << std::endl;
}


int main() {

    set s1;
    output(s1);

    set s2 = {44, 22, 11, 33, 55};
    output(s2);

    set s3(s2);
    output(s3);

    for (int i = 99; i > 0; i = i - 11) {
         std::cout << i << " " << s2.insert(i) << " " << s2.contains(i) << "; ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    output(s2);

    for (int i = 15; i < 100; i = i + 5) {
         std::cout << i << " " << s2.insert(i) << " " << s2.contains(i) << "; ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    output(s2);

    output(s3);

    s1 = s2;
    output(s1);

    s1.clear();
    output(s1);
    output(s2);
    output(s3);

    s1.insert(123);
    s1.insert(234);
    s1.insert(98);
    output(s1);

    std::cout << "Done." << std::endl;
}
```

## Output of program

When I compile and run, the output is:

```
SET OUTPUT: 
0 1 {}
END OF OUTPUT.
SET OUTPUT: 
5 0 {}
END OF OUTPUT.
SET OUTPUT: 
5 0 {}
END OF OUTPUT.
99 1 0; 88 1 0; 77 1 0; 66 1 0; 55 1 0; 44 1 0; 33 1 0; 22 1 0; 11 1 0; 
SET OUTPUT: 
14 0 {}
END OF OUTPUT.
15 1 0; 20 1 0; 25 1 0; 30 1 0; 35 1 0; 40 1 0; 45 1 0; 50 1 0; 55 1 0; 60 1 0; 65 1 0; 70 1 0; 75 1 0; 80 1 0; 85 1 0; 90 1 0; 95 1 0; 
SET OUTPUT: 
31 0 {}
END OF OUTPUT.
SET OUTPUT: 
5 0 {}
END OF OUTPUT.
SET OUTPUT: 
31 0 {}
END OF OUTPUT.
SET OUTPUT: 
0 1 {}
END OF OUTPUT.
SET OUTPUT: 
31 0 {}
END OF OUTPUT.
SET OUTPUT: 
5 0 {}
END OF OUTPUT.
SET OUTPUT: 
3 0 {}
END OF OUTPUT.
Done.
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

It is seen that sets do not have elements and the size of some of them are not correct. For example, set 2 after loop with **insert()** function should have had 9 elements but it does have 14 which means some of them were duplicated.

I've tried to visualize the operations done on sets using BST on paper but couldn't find where the problem is.

Comment: Here's a couple of general tips for programming: The first and most important is to not write large pieces of code without testing. Start extremely simple (i.e. empty `main` function and nothing more). Add a small little piece of code, build it, test it. Once it builds without warning and passes all tests, you continue with the next little piece of code. And if you already have a large program, then try to scale it back, simplify it bit by bit until the error disappears. Then add bits back in until the error comes back, then you know when and where you should concentrate your debugging.

Comment: And that brings us to the next point: *Debugging.* This is the typical way to solve problems like yours. Using a debugger you can catch crashes, or step through code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values and see how they change. Simplification and debugging are two crucial things that every programmer needs to know about.

Comment: Assigning to a function's (non-reference) argument has no effect outside that function. There is nothing special about pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have a common beginner misunderstanding. In your `inserthelper` function you have (abbreviated)

```
bool set::inserthelper(int i, set::treenode *node) {

    ...    
        node = new treenode(i);
    ...
            return (inserthelper(i, node->left));
    ...
            return (inserthelper(i, node->right));
    
}
```

`node =`  changes the `node` parameter **but that's all**. It does not change the pointer that was passed to `inserthelper`. It does not change `node->left` or `node->right` in the recursive calls to `inserthelper`. It does not change `root` in the `insert` method. The reason is that `node` is a **copy** of the pointer that was passed to the function. Changing it does not change the original pointer.

It's exactly the same with integers. If you wrote this code

```
int i = 10;
some_func(i);
cout << i << endl;

void some_func(int j)
{
   j = 11;
}
```

you would see the output `10` not `11` because `some_func` does not change the `i` variable. Many programmers understand this, but when pointers are involved they get confused and think the rules are different for pointers, but they are not. As molbdnilo said there's nothing special about pointers.

I guess the reason for the confusion is that when a pointer is passed to a function the pointer is copied, but what it is pointing to is not. Beginners might understand this but get confused and think that neither the pointer nor what it is being pointing to get copied. But that's incorrect. Often the key to understanding pointers is keeping clear in your mind the difference between the pointer itself and what the pointer is pointing to.

So there is a simple fix for your code. Change `inserthelper` to this

```
bool set::inserthelper(int i, set::treenode*& node) {
```

Using `&` makes `node` a reference, and so assigning to `node` really does change the original. `node` is now a reference to the original variable, not a copy of the original value.